# PrimeVUE - Datatable - Add a new record that opens in row editing mode

Tags: vue.js, datatables, primevue

I'd like to add a new record in a PrimeVue Datatable and I would the record to open in a row in edit mode. The documentation only shows this feature with a Dialog box.
https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase-v2/#/datatable/crud

Is there any way to adapt openNew() to add an empty row in edit mode instead of playing around with productDialog = true ?

```
<Toolbar class="p-mb-4">
    <template #left>
        <Button label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" class="p-button-success p-mr-2" @click="openNew" />
        <Button label="Delete" icon="pi pi-trash" class="p-button-danger" @click="confirmDeleteSelected"
:disabled="!selectedProducts || !selectedProducts.length" />
    </template>
</Toolbar>  

...

methods: {
    openNew() {
        this.product = {};
        this.submitted = false;
        this.productDialog = true;
    },
´´´

Many Thanks.
```